# e.target.id won't trigger clicking on elements residing within container.children[i].onclick

Tags: javascript, children

I have a list of different HTML items:

```
<ul id="listing">
  <li id="item-0">
    <div class="thumb">Can't get e.target.id clicking here :/</div>
    <div class="text">Can't get e.target.id clicking here :/</div>
  </li>
  <li id="item-1">
    <div class="thumb">Can't get e.target.id clicking here :/</div>
    <div class="text">Can't get e.target.id clicking here :/</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When clicking on `<li id="item-0">`, `<li id="item-1">` I want to get the id of the `<li>` - my problem though is, if I click on elements within the `<li>`, then I can't trigger the id.

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/77mawutq/**

Code:

```
var caseListingContainer = document.getElementById("listing");

for (var i = 0, len = caseListingContainer.children.length; i < len; i++)
{

    (function(index){
        caseListingContainer.children[i].onclick = function(e){
            alert(e.target.id);
        }    
    })(i);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` property refers to the element/object that the event was dispatched on and not to the owner of the handler. You can either use the `currentTarget` property of the event object or the `this` keyword instead of the `target` property.

```
e.currentTarget.id
```